# How to connect Oracle database 11g Server on FoxPro 9

Tags: oracle11g, visual-foxpro

How to connect remote oracle database 11g server in FoxPro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be relatively simple provided you have the data provider installed.

[I would start by looking at the connection string requirements](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/)

With that, you can get a handle to the database via

```
cConnectionString = "Driver = blah;Server=blah; etc from connection string website reference";
nHandle = SQLStringConnect( cConnectionString )

if nHandle < 1
   messagebox( "Unable to connect" )
   return
endif

*/ Once connected, you can then query the database
nResult = SQLExec( nHandle, "select * from yourTable", "cursorResultSentBackToVFPSide" )

if nResult < 1
   messagebox( "Error querying data" )
   return
endif

*/ If you need to parameterize something, a local variable in your routine can be used 
*/ and will be applied by using the "?" place-holder, such as

lnSomeIDYouWant = 1234
lcSQLCmd = "select * from SomeTable where SomeKey = ?lnSomeIDYouWant order by blah"
nResult = SQLExec( nHandle, lcSQLCmd, "C_VFPAlias" )

SQLDisconnect(nHandle)
```

The parameters can be of almost any type (except for things like general/binary which might need alternate measures, but the others like logical, numeric, date, string all no problems).